# How to create a Custom Pop Up for Task?

Tags: visualforce, datetime, popup, time

I want to create custom pop up for Tasks which will be opening on specified time .

Because standard task pop up will only come for Day wise(Again it will calculate based on starting of the day) and I have created a date/time field in task instead of standard **Due date**  to capture Time

How to Create a custom Pop up which will open automatically on that time ?